# How to create a Size field on Commerce product content fields?

Tags: commerce

I am new to [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and I have set up a store. But the problem is that adding variations for each product is a pain, especially when the product has more than 5 colors and 4 sizes.

What I want to do is to have a size Field in Content type instead of product type's fields so that I add the sizes only once (like choosing the categories or collection).

And then customers can select a radio button or so to be able to add the item to the Shopping Cart.

How can I make it work or is there another solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for another solution/approach, as detailed below ...

## Commerce Bulk Product Creation

You may want to use the [Commerce Bulk Product Creation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> ... facilitates the creation of groups of related products in bulk. Product administrators can select a number of options for various fields, and a product will be created for all possible combinations of these values. Out of the box, only list fields are supported for this, but an API exists to enable other types of fields for 'combination creation'.

**Attention**: this module doesn't have an official release yet (only an RC6), though with over 1.200 reported installs, it seems it is pretty stable / trustworthy.

## Commerce Backoffice

Another option is to use the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module, e.g. because of the ***auto creation of product display nodes***. It provides the backoffice functionality present in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), and contains these sub-modules:

- Commerce Backoffice **Product** (commerce_backoffice_product).
- Commerce Backoffice **Order** (commerce_backoffice_order).
- Commerce Backoffice **Content** (commerce_backoffice_content).

This module (and a few dependencies) provides the rich store owner experience that has made Commerce Kickstart 2 so popular (and prevents that you have to install the entire Commerce Kickstart distribution). And there is a [great video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZ_VcBan0) about it also.

**Note**: if you use [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), you most probably also want to use the [Shiny](https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny) administration theme, also used in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Comment: Ah great, first one is kinda working but there's one thing more that would make it perfect. when I add a bulk product, is there a way to include all fields related to the product display node to the same creation fields? (because this way I have to create a bulk product and then tap 'edit' and then set other fields as well.

Comment: @AbedNaseri I'm not aware about how you can do that "also" (using the 1st solution). However I'm pretty sure that you should be able to get that part to work via some type of "Views Bulk Operations (VBO)" aferwards (possibly by combining that with a custom VBO action implemented via the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module). If that makes sense to you, I'd suggest to post some type of followup question (with reference to this question if you want), to also try to answer your additional question in your prior comment (and maybe mark this answer as "accept"?).

Comment: I think I'll just go with the current way, so far is way faster than before. thank you:)